# What is PID 1025 on my Macbook Pro

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, terminal, command-line, javascript

I am on my Macbook pro and I restarted the machine about an hour ago. There is a process ID (PID 1025) that has been running for about 30 minutes and I do not know what it is. I wanted to understand what and why it's running before I kill it.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Node runs JavaScript code](https://nodejs.org/en/) and is typical for “enterprise” software like Adobe, Microsoft and others to use in the background when their apps need help to do thing.

In your case, Open Activity Monitor, set to View > All Processes, then search node [in either the Memory or CPU tabs].

Click the found process, then click the ***i*** Info icon.

My Mac show that this belongs to Adobe Photoshop, though I don't know exactly what it does.
`/Applications/Adobe Photoshop 2020/Adobe Photoshop 2020.app/Contents/MacOS/node`
Also note that the PID will be different every time, depending on how many other processes had been run before it.

It also shows it's currently using 0% CPU.
It quits when I quit Photoshop.

You’ll have to check your node to see where it sits on the file system to determine the source of your node process.